Mosquitto Access Control List (ACL) not working
I have a mosquitto MQTT broker running on a Windows machine. I'm trying to control the topics to which a certain user can subscribe an publish.
I've created a test user ("test") and added the user to the passwords file.
The client can connect to the broker and authenticate via username, password and SSL.
It can also receive published messages.
But whenever I add the ACL file to the per listener configuration, the client is not able to receive any published messages.
Here is my global configuration
per_listener_settings true

Here is my per listener configuration.
listener 9996
cafile C:\Certificates\ca.crt
certfile C:\Certificates\server.crt
keyfile C:\Certificates\server.key
require_certificate true
use_identity_as_username true
acl_file C:\mosquittoaccesscontrol.acl
password_file c:\mosquittopasswords.txt

And here is my ACL file configuration
user test
topic #


Ok. I found the problem. When you set:
use_identity_as_username true

It uses the Common Name (CN) from the client certificate as the MQTT username and as a result, the username is not the same as specified in the ACL file.
I've set use_identity_as_username false and now it is working.
